# gitlab runner errors occasionally

Tags: gitlab

I have gitlab setup with runners on dedicated VM machine (24GB 12 vCPUs and **very low runner concurrency=6**).

Everything worked fine until I've added more Browser tests - 11 at the moment.
These tests are in stage browser-test and start properly.

My problem is that, it sometimes succeeds and sometimes **not**, with totally random errors.

Sometimes it **cannot resolve hos**t, other times **unable to find element on page**..

If I rerun these failed tests, all goes green.

Anyone has an idea on what is going wrong here?

BTW... I've checked, this dedicated VM is not overloaded...

Comment: Why downvote? I believe I will stick to stackoverflow  no matter what...:( Or you can give me a hint on where to post this question, cause I'm kinda confused with all these stackoverflow clones

Comment: What are logs showing? The problem I see with your question is that your description may be meaningful to someone who has done exactly the same thing as you already, but it appears to be lacking a lot of context to me, who isn't super familiar with the specifics of gitlab runners. Explaining the purpose of the system, or more information about the configuration and the expected behavior may help us understand your question better. None of the votes have been that it is off-topic. They have all been that right now you've dumped a very broad problem that may have lots of possible solutions.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for the explanation. Now I get it. I will dig into logs to post more data. However tracing them in 10 concurrently running docker images with at least one children each is not nicest thing to do especially when they are destroyed on completion. That's why I posted pretty simple question, hoping anybody already had this problem in the past...